# What does sum [i++] mean in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I was practising Java and now I am stuck in a problem. I am not able to 
understand what does this code mean. Would anybody explain step by step?

The whole program is a program for addition of two binary numbers:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exercise17 {
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  long binary1, binary2;
  int i = 0, remainder = 0;
  int[] sum = new int[20];
  Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.print("Input first binary number: ");
   binary1 = in.nextLong();
   System.out.print("Input second binary number: ");
   binary2 = in.nextLong();

   while (binary1 != 0 || binary2 != 0) 
  {
 sum[i++] = (int)((binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) % 2);
 remainder = (int)((binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) / 2);
  binary1 = binary1 / 10;
   binary2 = binary2 / 10;
   }
  if (remainder != 0) {
 sum[i++] = remainder;
 }
  --i;
  System.out.print("Sum of two binary numbers: ");
  while (i >= 0) {
  System.out.print(sum[i--]);
}
System.out.print("\n");  
}
}
```

Tell me what does this line means:

```
 sum[i++] = (int)((binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) % 2);
```

What does sum[i++] mean, and what does this whole statement mean?

Comment: Why do you ask the community instead of reading about Java operators? You cannot master programming by asking bits and pieces here and there.

Comment: reading docs or tutorials would help you

Comment: You are expected to do **serious** research prior asking questions here. You could have saved you the time putting up the (nicely) formatted question ... and instead have asked a search engine. You would have gotten your answer 10 minutes ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sum[i++] = 2;
```

Means the same as this:

```
sum[i] = 2;
i = i + 1;
```

sum is an array and we write sum[number] to access its element

i++ is a postfix incrementer. It adds one to number after current statement finished running. (Basically adds a line of code "i  = i + 1" after current line)